# What is a good Twitter PHP library other than Zend?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

What is a good Twitter PHP Library other than Zend?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you find lacking in Zend's implementation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i display twitter tweets from twitter  using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822116/how-do-i-display-twitter-tweets-from-twitter-using-php)

Comment: Mike B- I tried using the Zend framework on my Mac but I could not get it to work for some reason. Given the responses, I may try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my several projects I've used [TwitterOAuth](http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)

Comment: zerkms - I have had issues with TwitterOAuth i.e. I can't seem to get back an access token when I specify both the Key and Secret. I am wondering if maybe my problem is a network issue. Thoughts?

Comment: @coolcajun: give some code please. Add the problem code to the question and slap me here.

Comment: @calmcajun: If you hare having issues with multiple OAuth libraries you should make sure you can connect to https://api.twitter.com from your server and that the clock on the server is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Check out: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php